# How to display notes at specific points of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

To see what I mean:

Please take a look at the following site: http://bikeboard.at/Board/Fesche-Waesche-Bikewear-2015-th211009 (and search for the term "Smith Overtake").

Now above the text you can see an image that has several markers (circles) on it. When you hover over one of them a note is displayed with additional information on that part of the image.

I am mainly interested in the output and not the input/editing of the markings.

I found a jQuery plugin called [imgNotes](https://github.com/waynegm/imgNotes) that does something similar. But it seems to be an overkill, because of its editor feature.

The notes should contain an image, text and a link to another page.

What other possible solutions do you know?

Comment: That is CSS. In /style/layout_1441719911.css, line 3490, selector ".highlight_frame:hover .highlighttext" defined "visibility: visible;"

Answer (score 3):

If you've solved it yourself, great - it'd be awesome if you could share some code!

[Here's a jQuery-only, CSS-free implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/7cvf9kj1/). It could use some polishing up and accept some config options, but you get the general idea :).

```
$.fn.addNotes = function(notes){
var $img = $(this);
var pos = $img.position();
var w = $img.outerWidth();
var h = $img.outerHeight();
var offsetX = pos.left;
var offsetY = pos.top;
var $imgparent = $img.parent();
$imgparent.on('mouseenter','.point', function(){
    $(this).next('.note').show();
}).on('mouseout', '.point', function(){
   $(this).next('.note').hide(); 
});
$.each(notes, function(idx,note){
    var $point = $('<div/>').addClass('point').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: (Number(offsetX)+note.pos.x)+'px',
        top: (Number(offsetY)+note.pos.y)+'px',
        width: '10px',
        height: '10px',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        background:'#f00'
    });
    var $note = $('<div/>').addClass('note').html(note.note).css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: 15+(Number(offsetX)+note.pos.x)+'px',
        top: (Number(offsetY)+note.pos.y)+'px',
        background:'#fff',
        padding:'5px'
    }).hide();
   $img.after($point); 
   $point.after($note);
});
};
```

Sample usage:

```
var notes = [
{ pos: { x: 100, y: 100 }, note: 'Hello world!' },
{ pos: { x: 200, y: 100 }, note: 'Hello Harry!' },
{ pos: { x: 100, y: 200 }, note: 'Hello Ron!' },
{ pos: { x: 300, y: 300 }, note: 'Hello Hermione!' }
];

$('img').addNotes(notes);
```

Comment: I was resposible for the input and a team mate created the output. I can't post anything yet, as the project is not yet finished/public. I'll try to update my answer as soon as it is on air.

Comment: I forgottto keep you updated. The result of the project can be seen here: https://www.1000ps.at/wallpaper-ducati-959-panigale-mega-poster-11

Answer (score 1):

As hm_ngr indicated in the comments: We solved this using simple CSS, no JavaScript at all.

- The points are positioned using left/top via percentage. This makes it possible to create a responsive output.
- The notes are simple divs that are only visible on `:hover`

The input of the points and notes is a custom implementation that stores the left/top coordinates via percentage in our database (poster 1:n poster_points).

I hope this helps someone.